Package manager locked up, can't install or do anything
Alright, I accidently hit ctrl+c while I was updating software... and now it seems as though there's nothing I can do to fix it. No matter what I put in, any option of apt or apt-get, it just denies it. Like so:
sudo apt install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aptitude : Depends: libapt-pkg5.0 (>= 1.1) but it is not installable
            Depends: libboost-iostreams1.67.0 but it is not installable
            Depends: libboost-system1.67.0 but it is not installable
            Depends: libcwidget3v5 (>= 0.5.17-8) but it is not installable
            Depends: libxapian30 (>= 1.4.10~) but it is not installed
            Recommends: libparse-debianchangelog-perl but it is not installable
 gcc-11 : Depends: libcc1-0 (>= 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) but it is not installed
          Depends: binutils (>= 2.38) but it is not installed
          Depends: libgcc-11-dev (= 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) but it is not installed
          Recommends: libc6-dev (>= 2.13-0ubuntu6) but it is not installed
 libreoffice-draw : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.4) but 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is installed
 libreoffice-gtk3 : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.4) but 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is installed
 libreoffice-math : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.4) but 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is installed
 libstdc++-11-dev : Depends: libgcc-11-dev (= 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libc6-dev (>= 2.13-0ubuntu6) but it is not installed
 python3-uno : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.4) but 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is installed or
                        libreoffice-core-nogui (= 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.4) but it is not installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies

How can I correct these dependency issues outside of the package manager? I have a feeling I won't be able to use it.

What version of Ubuntu? The version of libxapian30 it wants looks older than than any supported version uses.

Please edit your question to show the complete output of sudo apt update and of sudo apt upgrade
